# Gradle Fails to resolve material-dialogs dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

I am trying to build my Android App I imported from a Git repository. This same app builds correctly in another environment, but in my environment I get the following error:

```
Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.7.0
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.7.0'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.2.1@aar'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

I also tried different versions (0.7.7.0, 0.7.6.0, 0.7.5.5), but nothing changes. How can I address my issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [jCenter](https://bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/material-dialogs/#files/com/afollestad/material-dialogs) there are only two version available 0.7.9.0 and 0.7.9.1. These versions are not available in Maven Central, so check in your project `build.gradle` that you are using `jcenter()`.

BTW these versions are not updated, the last version released in [GitHub](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) is 0.8.5.1.

To use the last version in your project use the following instructions:

> **Repository**
>
> First, add the following to your app's build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> repositories {
>   maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }  
> }
> ```
>
> **Core**
>
> The core module contains all the major classes of this library,
>   including MaterialDialog and AlertDialogWrapper. You can create basic,
>   list, single/multi choice, progress, input, etc. dialogs with core.
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>
>   // ... other dependencies here
>
>   compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar') {
>       transitive = true
>   }   
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `targetSdkVersion 22`. If you update `targetSdkVersion`  to 23 and use this latest library version in denendency the problem'll go away:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }   
}
```

But if you want to use 22 SDK you should use such dependencies:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }  
    }     

compile ('com.github.afollestad:material-dialogs:53103863a6') {
    transitive = true
}
```

This is the last version which supports 22 SDK - **v. 0.6.4.4**. But there is some problem with using old version number in dependency name (maybe because library author migrated to jCenter) and you can use first 10 digits of commit's hash related to [this version](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/releases/tag/v0.6.4.4) instead.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use this:

```
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.1.0'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.7.0'
```